# Fire event when caret enters span element in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, dom-events

I have a content editable div with a span like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">some <span>spanned</span> text</div>
```

And I would like to know if there are any event listeners I can attach to the `span` element itself that can be used to detect if the caret moves inside the `span` element.

I am not looking for an answer where there are listeners attached to the `div`, running a check every time there is activity in the `div`, such as the solution to this answer:

[Firing an event when the caret gets within a particular div/span/a tag and also, when the caret leaves the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004757/firing-an-event-when-the-caret-gets-within-a-particular-div-span-a-tag-and-also)

Comment: have you resolved your issue?

Comment: No, but I haven't worked actively to find a solution. It seems to be unsupported, but I just found out that there is a selection event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event

Comment: It looks like select event has unknown compatibility with IE.

Comment: Yes. It looks like a pheripherical feature in the standards that they haven't invested much in getting to work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). And check for `characterData` changes in the observer callback.

Here is an example:

```js
var MutationObserver = 
  window.MutationObserver || 
  window.WebKitMutationObserver || 
  window.MozMutationObserver;

var config = { childList: true, characterData: true, characterDataOldValue:true, subtree: true };

var target = document
.querySelector('div[contenteditable]')
.getElementsByTagName('span')
.item(0);

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
  if (mutation.type === 'characterData') {
   console.clear();
   console.log('old value:', mutation.oldValue);
   console.log('new value:', mutation.target.textContent);
  }
 });
});

observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">some <span>spanned</span> text</div>
```

To check if the caret just entered the `span` a simple `click` listener should do the job.

```js
var target = document
.querySelector('div[contenteditable]')
.getElementsByTagName('span')
.item(0)
.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
 console.log('caret entered:', evt.target)
})
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">some <span>spanned</span> text</div>
```

Comment: I thought about using mutation observers, but will this also fire if the caret just enters the span, because that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: As Daniel writes in another answer: there are many ways that the caret can enter the span, including keyboard events, so just looking for click events doesn't really solve the issue.

Comment: David, moving caret by keyboard arrow doesn't fire a click event on "spanned" word.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to know where user inputs is `document.getSelection()` which gives a few node references like the `baseNode` and the current `focusNode` along with useful offset informations.

You can then use a `selectionchange` event on the `document` to know when the cursor moves around without checking if the mouse is being moved/clicked nor using keyboard events.

```js
var out, itm; // saved to spare processor time

document.addEventListener('selectionchange',
function(ev) { // called whenever keycursor moves
  
  // find and save our main HTML objects
  if (!out) out = document.getElementById('out');
  if (!itm) itm = document.querySelector('span');

  // get the user selection informations
  let grab = document.getSelection(),
    text = grab.baseNode ||0, //  <-- clicked here
    node = text.parentNode; // <-- container


  out.innerHTML = // now print where we're at~

  // nowhere near the span, showing a hint
  !node?"Well, try moving around the span ..":

  // peaking inside the output, wrong way
  node == out?"You're grabbing me out ...":

  // checked around, let's check for the node
  (node == itm?'inside ': // inside span itself

  // check if we're selecting the whole node
  grab.containsNode(itm)?'found in ':

  // check if at least we selected a part of it
  grab.containsNode(itm.firstChild)?'partial ':

  'other ') + // seemingly somewhere else ...


  node.nodeName + // write which node we found
  ' > ' + // and show a bit of the contents
  (text.data || text.innerText).substr(0, 24);
})
```

```css
body > div {border: 1px solid; font-size: xlarge;}
#out {background: black; color: white; margin: 1em}
div > span {color: red;} * {padding: 1ex 1em}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  This is a text before
  <span>this span</span>
  in middle of the text
</div>

<div id="out">focus NODE > contents ...</div>
```

---

Now this might get very confusing with 100's of nodes to check... You didn't want bound/timed listeners or custom nodes, so I'd personally recommend going with the classic event listeners.

You can generate `caret` events on the selection-start node, with :

> document.addEventListener('selectionchange', ev => document.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.dispatchEvent(new Event('caret')))

Then use the classic HTML listeners :

> span.addEventListener('caret', function callback() { /* ... */ });

Note that you'll have to check for a caret move in neightbor-HTML-children to know whether it goes off your span with this approach; it might be interesting to store which node is active so you can `caretIn` and `caretOut` as proposed in Daniel's answer ... Here is a simple implementation :

```
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', ev => {
    var node = (document.getSelection().baseNode||0).parentNode,
        old = document.lastGrab;        if (node === old) return;
    if (old) old.dispatchEvent(new Event('caretOut'));
    (document.lastGrab = node).dispatchEvent(new Event('caretIn'));
});

var node = document.querySelector('span'); // find it the way you want
node.addEventListener('caretIn', function callback() { /* ... */ });
node.addEventListener('caretOut', function callback() { /* ... */ });
```

Hope you now have what you needed; Happy coding :)

Comment: Not what the question is asking

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when thinking about it - I can't really find any appropriate native event to address this issue.

The thing is... A caret can be set in many ways, click, selection (which can start or end in the area you wish to detect), keyboard events moving the cursor or even external scripts.

There is no event which capture them all.

Sadly, I believe the only way of doing so, is looping and checking whether the current selection (which holds the caret data) is a good match.

To enable what you wish for, I've implemented a new element using [CustomElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements),
The implementation is mostly about letting you use any syntax you want - 
whether it is: `myElement.dispatchEvent('caretin')`
or just using the html tag syntax `<caret-detector oncaretin="myFunction(event,'myArg')"></caret-detector>`.

I don't claim this is the best idea ever, nor the best implementation of the current idea, but I think it covers all cases using one loop, and a native js/html approach.

```js
//Create Appropriate Events And initialize them
var CaretInEvent = document.createEvent('Event'),
  CaretOutEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
CaretInEvent.initEvent('caretin',true,true);
CaretOutEvent.initEvent('caretout',true,true);

//Next section will provide the caret handling functionallity
const CaretDetectorTagName = "caret-detector";
class CaretDetector extends HTMLElement {
      //these will be used in order to support switching element in focus
 static get lastDetected(){
  return CaretDetector._lastDetected;
 }
 static set lastDetected(element){
  CaretDetector._lastDetected = element;
 }
    //the interval
 static detectorStart(){
  setInterval(function(){
   let focusNode = document.getSelection().focusNode;
   if(focusNode){
    focusNode = focusNode.parentNode.closest(CaretDetectorTagName) || focusNode.parentNode;
    if(CaretDetector.lastDetected && focusNode !== CaretDetector.lastDetected && CaretDetector.lastDetected.inStatus === true && CaretDetector.lastDetected.triggerCaretOut){
     CaretDetector.lastDetected.dispatchEvent(CaretOutEvent);
    }
    if(focusNode.triggerCaretIn && focusNode.inStatus !== true){
     focusNode.dispatchEvent(CaretInEvent);
     CaretDetector.lastDetected = focusNode;
    }
   }
  },100);
 }
 //start with listening to the mentioned events
 constructor(){
  super();
  this._instatus = false;
  this.addEventListener('caretin', (...args)=>{
   this._instatus = true;
   this.triggerCaretIn(...args);
  });
  this.addEventListener('caretout', (...args)=>{
   this._instatus = false;
   this.triggerCaretOut(...args);
  });
 }
   
 get inStatus(){
  return this._instatus;
 }
   
 triggerCaretIn(event){
  let desiredFn = this.getAttribute('oncaretin'),
  wrapperFunction = new Function('event',`${desiredFn};`);
  wrapperFunction(event); 
 }
   
 triggerCaretOut(event){
  let desiredFn = this.getAttribute('oncaretout'),
  wrapperFunction = new Function('event',`${desiredFn};`);
  wrapperFunction(event); 
 }
}
    
//actually connect the tag-name with the above class
customElements.define(CaretDetectorTagName, CaretDetector);

//the functions you want to execute when caret is in or out
function inFn(event){
 console.log(event.srcElement.id + ": in");
}

function outFn(event){
 console.log(event.srcElement.id + ": out");
}
  
window.onload = CaretDetector.detectorStart;
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
 012345
 <caret-detector id="object1" oncaretin="inFn(event)" oncaretout="outFn(event)">STRING OF OBJECT 1</caret-detector>
 <caret-detector id="object2" oncaretin="inFn(event)" oncaretout="outFn(event)">STRING OF OBJECT 2</caret-detector>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using `setInverval` isn't really safe. It is unlikely but possible that the cursor moves past the span in less than 100 ms.

Comment: You are right, but please say - what is the scenario? A more aggressive approach is to make the loop much faster (maybe without setTimeout/Interval) on a different thread using Web Workers... much like a digest loop in angular, what is the difference?  anyway - A very interesting problem indeed